# Logging microservice requests and responses to MongoDB asynchronously using AOP or Solace?

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, microservices, spring-aop, solace

I have multiple Java REST microservice APIs and I would like to log their requests and responses to MongoDB. Do I create a separate logging API with an asynchronous service method and call it from all other microservice controller classes using AOP? Or Do I use event brokers like Solace/Kafka where the microservices publish the logs to a topic and a separate service picks and stores in MongoDB?
Which is the better way, I can afford to lose some logs without being stored in MongoDB but I cannot afford to affect the performance of my microservices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are definitely advantages to using an event broker to handle log data, since it can serve as a buffer during times when the logging API isn't available or slow.  Note that AOP could also be used with an event broker, it would just use a event endpoint, rather than an HTTPS endpoint.

A couple other related points:

- Have you considered persistence layers other than MongoDB?  [OpenTelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/) backends are made to address exactly the sort of use case you have, and provide some very useful tooling for auditing/troubleshooting microservices.
- Rather than using REST, how about [connecting the microservices themselves through an event broker](https://solace.com/solutions/initiative/microservices/).  It could provide some very nice performance benefits, and make your microservices more agile.

Best,
Jesse

Comment: totally agree and I like that approach! The use of an advanced event broker and openTel is a good combination for a tracing solution in a microservices architecture. Using Solace as the event broker of choice will give you the advantage of multi-protocol support so you can trigger your AOP service via a REST call from the broker and you can send events over to the broker from your Java microservices via the Solace Java API